# What are some good map charts?

Tags: php, flash, charts

I've googled tons of times but i really find flash map charts where you rollover and get a value. i already checked out anychart, anything better?

P.S. I don't want static image charts.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "map charts?" An image map? A geographic map?

Comment: Yes, a map like the ones in google analytics, you roll over on each country and you get the population/visits/etc..

Comment: Well, you can use the Google Charts API to produce the same charts that Analytics has.

Comment: I'm asking the same @Ben

Answer (score 1):

*To turn my comment into an answer:*

If you want charts like Google Analytics, you can use the Google interactive charts API to create interactive maps. It's the same API. See: [Google Goemap Visualization Examples](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html#Example)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AmMap http://www.ammap.com/ As far as I understand it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

PHP/Swf is probably fit for your requirements

http://www.maani.us/charts/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a jquery plugin http://www.jqplot.com and avoid flash.
You can generate the input for the graphs using php.